# C++ standard library implementations in different compilers

Tags: c++, stl, std

I was wondering which C++ standard libraries are in use in different C++ compilers. I tried searching for it, but couldn't find a comprehensive list.

I know Dinkumware's implementation is used by msvc and icc, libstdc++ is used by gcc, and libc++ is used in clang. But what about Digital Mars C++, or Embarcadero's bcc, or IBM's xlC++?

Comment: Note that clang can also use `libstdc++`.

Comment: Current icc uses gcc std libraries, I think. Anyway, I am curious as to why you would require this info?

Comment: @user93353: In my particular case, nothing that important actually. Just a discussion among colleagues that led to this question. And I got more curious, since I couldn't just find a list of that information.

Comment: Sun, to name something  omitted,  is shipped with two  libraries (one  based on rw,  the other on stlport)  and  can also use apache  library..   shouldn't this  be in the compiler documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A shortlist:

- GCC: uses its own libstdc++.
- MSVC: uses its own msvcrp, which is bought from Dinkumware, then dismembered to work around MSVC's bad C++ language support (so it's not really Dinkumware anymore).
- Clang: uses LLVM's libc++ if passed the `-stdlib=libc++` option. It can also use GCC's libstdc++ and in also MSVC's library (it generates binary compatible code in all cases).
- ICC: uses GCC libstdc++ on Linux and MSVC's library on Windows. It also tries to mimick both compilers on these platforms.

Note there are other compilers and (independent) C++ standard library implementations I have not covered here.